# Elasticsearch Shard distribution size differs enormously

Tags: elasticsearch, optimization, bigdata, real-time, sharding

I need to load 1.2 billion documents in the elasticsearch. As of today we have 6 nodes in the cluster. To equally distribute the shards among the 6 nodes I have mentioned the number of shards to be 42. I use spark and it takes me almost 3 days load the index. The shards distribution looks so off.

[image]

The node6 only has two shards in it while node 2 has almost 10 shards. The size distribution is also not even. Some shards are 114.6gb while some are just 870mb within the same node.

I have tried to figure out the solution too. I can include the
`index.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node: 7`
while creating the index and make it evenly distribute. Will forcing the designated amount of shards in the node, crash the node if there is not enough resource available?

I want to size the shards evenly. My index size is 900 gb apprx. I want each shards to be atleast 20 gb. Could I use the following setting while creating the index?
`max_primary_shard_size: 25gb`
Is setting up max shard size only possible through ilm policy and will I require roll over policy for that ? I am not too familiar with the ilm. Sorry if this does not make sense.

The main reason I am trying to optimize the index is because I am getting timeout error on my application when I am querying the elastic search. I know I can increase my timeout time in my application and do some query optimization, but first I want to optimize my index and make my application as fast as possible.

I load the index only one time and do not write any documents to it after onetime load. For additional data, which i load every 15 days, I create a different index  and use an alias name on the both the indexes to query. Other than sharding if there is any suggestion to optimize my indexes I will really appreciate it. It takes me 3 days just to load the data so it is quite difficult to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

are you using custom routing values in your indexing approach? that might explain the shard size differences.
and if you aren't already, disable replicas and refreshes when doing your bulk index, as that will speed things up

finally your shard size of 20gig is probably a little low, I would suggest doubling that size, aiming for <50gig

Comment: I am not using any custom routing values while creating index. I am just using the following attribute in my setting:
`"index": {"number_of_shards": 42}`
As far as my understanding goes if we do not mention the routing values should not the elasticsearch itself distributes the documents equally among the shards. Am I missing something here?

Comment: it should, yes, which is why I asked about the routing. without more details on the ingestion process, we're just guessing